# Is there any way to find out how many indices under given name are there in a TextureAtlas?

Tags: libgdx

In LibGDX you can load a bunch of images named, for example, `image_1.png`, `image_2.png`, `image_3.png` etc and then get those by name and index from `TextureAtlas` like this:

```
atlas.findRegion(name, index);
```

But is there a way to obtain all indices of images with a particular name? Or at least a number of images with that name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is [`TextureAtlas.findRegions(...)`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureAtlas.html#findRegions%28java.lang.String%29):

```
TextureAtlas atlas = ...;
Array<TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion> regions = atlas.findRegions("image_1");
int indices = regions.size;
```